# Getting an error making a post request with guzzle http

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I am trying to get a list of banks from an external endpoint using guzzle http with the following code

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$request = $client->post('http://staging1flutterwave.co:8080/pwc/rest/fw/banks/');


dd($response = $request->getBody());
```

This endpoint takes no parameters but must be sent as HTTP POST.
I am getting this error i can't seem to figure out after some goggling.
I am using  Guzzle library version 6.3

> count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Comment: The error is probably not related to the code in you posted. Could you please post a full stack trace and the relevant code? You could also comment the guzzle request, you'll probably still get the error.

Comment: I have faced this issue when I was running an old Laravel application on the latest PHP version 7.3, this error was coming for Laravel paginator, that could be the issue in following application: http://staging1flutterwave.co:8080/pwc/rest/fw/banks/